# Can someone explain the concept of indirect heaps/indirect priority queues to me?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I have to build an indirect heap for a project, and I don't quite understand what it means. If you're building a heap out of an array, is implementing indirection simply adding some sort of map data structure to associate each item with its index? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Indirect Heap means nothing by itself. You can do indirect heap sorting, indirect heap *any algorithm really*...  Indirect heap just mean "without changing what is stored on the heap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An indirect heap is a heap in which the data items stored are indexes into a list, array, or other data structure that holds the actual items.

Imagine that you have a list of names: `["jim","joe","bob","sam","susan","kelly","jessica"]` from which you want to build a heap. A direct heap would have:

```
         bob
    joe        jessica
sam   susan  jim    kelly
```

An indirect heap would replace the names in the heap with indexes into the list:

```
         2
    1        6
 3     4   0   5
```

Your comparison functions have to change. Rather than comparing `heap[0]` with `heap[1]`, you end up comparing `list[heap[0]]` with `list[heap[1]]`.

Some people call that a semi-indirect heap. A direct heap, in their parlance, contains an additional mapping from the name to the index.